# How can I get the size of a static View?

Tags: android

I want to obtain the height of a custom View so the animation can cover all the size of the layout, no matter what device is being used. The problem is, the View needs to be static, so when I try to get its height, it says I can't call a non-static method from a static class.

```
private static class EjemploView extends View {

     private Path path = new Path();
     private static float Last_X = 0;
     private static float Last_Y = 0;

    public EjemploView (Context context) {

        super(context);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                y=30;

                while(true){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
                        if(!direction)
                        {
                        y=y+StepY_Figura;
                        }
                        else
                        {   
                            y=y-StepY_Figura;                            
                        }
                        if(y<30)
                        {
                            direction=false;                                
                            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                            Thread.sleep(350);
                        }

                        if(y>260)
                        {
                            direction=true;                             
                            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                            Thread.sleep(350);                              
                        }
                        postInvalidate();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
          }).start();          


    }

@Override

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    float x = canvas.getWidth() / 4;
    float x2=x;


    if(Unaprueba==true)
    {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    else
    {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);  
    }
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 30, paint);
    x =x+x2+4;
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 30, paint);
    x =x+x2+4;
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 30, paint);
    String s =Integer.toString(sleeptime);
    canvas.drawText("RITHM: "+s, 10, 20, paint);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  float eventX = event.getX();
  float eventY = event.getY();
  int Change_coordY=10;
  int Change_Delay=5;
  int Minimum_Delay=5;
  switch (event.getAction()) {
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    //path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
    Last_X=eventX;
    Last_Y=eventY;

    return true;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


      if(eventY>Last_Y+Cambio_coordY)
      {           
          sleeptime=sleeptime-Change_Delay;
          if(sleeptime<=Minimum_Delay)
          {
              sleeptime=Minimum_Delay;
          }

      }
      else if(eventY<Last_Y-Change_coordY)
      {
          sleeptime=sleeptime+Change_Delay;

      }
    break;
  default:
    return false;
  }

  invalidate();
  return true;
}    
}
```

Do you know if there is any way I can get the size of the layout if the View is static? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does the view need to be static?

Comment: try using a viewTreeObserver and you could get the height